# Create shared library for cluster enviroment in websphere

Tags: java, websphere

I have clustered environment for my project, the problem that iam facing is that my project is created by `JSF 2.0 Mojarra` and the `WebSphere` has 1.2 so this make a lot of conflict.

I read about the shared library in  `WebSphere` to solve this problem my question is, Is there a way of creating one shared library exist in the node manager server and this shared library used by all available nodes in this clustered environment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need a shared library.
What you should do is to change your classloader policy so that you first load the JSF 2.0 library you have inside your App.

In order to do this you have to change you classloader policy to **Parent Last**.
In the WAS console you can do this by choosing `Enterprise Applications > MyApp > Class loading and update detection > Set the Class loader order to Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)` , Save to Master Configuration, Synchronize with Node and Restart the application.